# How to get ID of last inserted row by QSqlQuery.lastInsertId() from SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, pyqt

How can I get ID of last inserted row from SQL Server by `PyQt4.QtSql` module? Now I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express, but program has to work also on SQL Server 2000.

Here is my code (Python + PyQt) and results:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4 import QtSql

app = QApplication([])
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
db.setDatabaseName('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;')
db.open()

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.prepare("""CREATE TABLE Test(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Row nvarchar(255)
)
""")
query.exec_()

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.prepare('INSERT Test OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES(?)')
query.bindValue(0, 'Test')

query.exec_()

while query.next():
    last_inserted_id = query.value(0)

print('OUTPUT: ', last_inserted_id)
print('QSqlQuery.lastInsertId: ', query.lastInsertId())

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()')

while query.next():
    last_inserted_id_ = query.value(0)

print('SCOPE_IDENTITY: ', last_inserted_id_)

db.close()
```

**Results:**

```
OUTPUT:  1
QSqlQuery.lastInsertId:  None
SCOPE_IDENTITY:  <PyQt4.QtCore.QPyNullVariant object at 0x00000000032D88D0>
```

Unfortunately `OUTPUT` Clause is supported by SQL Server 2005 or above.

Python 3.2.3 (x64), PyQt 4.9.4, SQL Server 2012 Express

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

So far I use `SELECT @@IDENTITY`.

Comment: ever thought of using e.g. [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)?

Comment: @dav1d SQLAlchemy support SQL Server via pyodbc. I don't need additional libraries if I use PyQt. From pyodbc FAQ: "SQL Server also provides SCOPE_IDENTITY() which is supposed to fix this. Unfortunately the SQL Server ODBC driver calls an internal stored procedure for each execute call which messes up the scoping, making this unusable." http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs#SQL_Server

Comment: I don't know Python, but I think SCOPE_IDENTITY() only works within a batch.  So, you might want to add the ;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the query with the INSERT.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @GilM You're right. Thanks. Now it works on SQL Server 2000 as well as 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer to allow this to be closed cleanly:

I don't know Python, but I think SCOPE_IDENTITY() only works within a batch. So, you might want to add the ;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the query with the INSERT. Hope this helps.

So your Insert could look like:

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery() 
query.prepare('INSERT Test VALUES(?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()') 
query.bindValue(0, 'Test') 

query.exec_() 

while query.next(): 
    last_inserted_id = query.value(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

QSqlQuery Class has a method lastInsertId which returns the id of the last inserted row.

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery() 
query.exec_('INSERT Test (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Test')')

# Get the ID of the last inserted row
query.lastInsertId() # Output : 1
```

Comment: Note that the result from QSqlQuery::lastInsertId is only valid if the query was successful and the underlying database reported back inserted id.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId