# Can't retrieve identity field after insert in sql database

Tags: c++, qt, sql-server-2008

Using C++ Qt framework and sql server 2008 I've been trying to insert a record into a table with an identity field and retrieve the identity value. Below is a simplified code sample which actually does do the insert but just doesn't retreive the identity. The identity returned from query.value(0) is an invalid QVariant.

```
QSqlQuery query(*pConn);
query.prepare("insert into [VH_MANUFACTURER]  values ('sRRS test man code','RRS type','RRS logo file',1,'RRS SEO para','RRS description','RS');"
"select SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
if(query.exec())
{
    if(query.next())
    {
        QVariant identity =   query.value(0);
        int id=identity.toInt();
    }
}
```

I've tried using select @@identity instead of scope_identity with no improvement and also  QSqlQuery .lastInsertId() which also returns an invalid QVariant, see below.

```
  bool bFeature = pConn->driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::LastInsertId);

QSqlQuery query(*pConn);
query.prepare("insert into [VH_MANUFACTURER] ([MFG_NAME],[MFG_TYPE],[MFG_LOGO],[MFG_ACTIVE],[MFG_SEO_CONTENT],[MFG_DESCRI],[MFG_CAPMANCODE]) values ('sRRS test man code','RRS type','RRS logo file',1,'RRS SEO para','RRS description','RS')");
if(query.exec())
{
    QVariant id=query.lastInsertId();
}
```

hasFeature returns true, so the driver is supposed to support what I'm trying to do.
Just to test the sql , I ran the sql directly through Sql Server Management Studio and it inserts as expected and returns the identity value correctly.

Comment: Does your `QSqlQuery` support multiple statements in one string???

Comment: I can't say for sure but the insert works correctly and query.next() returns true when select scope_identity is used and returns false when it's not used.

Comment: Try `query.prepare("insert into [VH_MANUFACTURER]  values ('sRRS test man code','RRS type','RRS logo file',1,'RRS SEO para','RRS description','RS'); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();");`

Comment: Isn't that what I've written in the question?

Comment: No, just try to run this

Comment: But it's identical to what I've written in the question .

Comment: Identical? I remove `""` between strings. Will you try or not?

Comment: c++ wise that's identical. I tried it all the same but same result.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618200/5070879), in Python the use while, maybe you could try to execute `query.next()` one more time.

Comment: I used that question when I tried lastInsertId and got the same result , an invalid QVariant.

Comment: tried while statement but no joy, only one item in collection it seems.

Comment: Last suggestion, specify columns explicitly`insert into [VH_MANUFACTURER] (col_1, col2, col3, ...) values ` I don't like you depend of column order which is undefined, maybe in SSMS it works, but Qt may not map correctly. Check also `QSqlDriver::hasFeature().` `QSqlDriver::LastInsertId 7 Whether the driver supports returning the Id of the last touched row.`

Comment: Same result, thanks for suggestions, will check QSqlDriver::hasFeature()

Comment: Checked with QSqldriver.hasFeature(QSqlDriver::LastInsertId) and the feature is supported.

Comment: So if it has LastInsertId capability it means it didn't INSERT this rows. Check using SSMS

Comment: I've been checking each insert with SSMS and the inserts are working fine

Comment: Not a Microsoft SQL expert, but have you tried removing both the SELECT statement and the call to `QSqlQuery::next()` before calling `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()`? The reason I ask is that lastInsertId() assumes the last SQL statement was an insert.

Comment: @MrEricSir thanks for suggestion, yes I've tried both of those. There's a post on internet suggesting a sql server 2008 driver bug associated with this issue, unfortunatley the link to the ms website comes up 404. I think maybe this is the next avenue to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a work around using OUTPUT clause in sql. I don't exactly know why the other methods I tried don't work. There is a [sql server bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2019779) associated with this feature but that doesn't explain why it worked in ssms but not in c++ Qt code. The sample below show's the work around. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value) the reference I used to solve this.

```
bool bFeature = pConn->driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::LastInsertId);

QSqlQuery query(*pConn);
query.prepare("insert into [VH_MANUFACTURER] ([MFG_NAME],[MFG_TYPE],[MFG_LOGO],[MFG_ACTIVE],[MFG_SEO_CONTENT],[MFG_DESCRI],[MFG_CAPMANCODE]) OUTPUT INSERTED.MFG_ID values ('sRRS test man code','RRS type','RRS logo file',1,'RRS SEO para','RRS description','RS')");
if(query.exec())
{
    if(query.next())
    {
         QVariant id=query.value("MFG_ID");
    }

}
```